# How to get all columns as rows in MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB like this one:

```
> NAME     |   VALUE
>--------------------
> Jon      |    0.2
> Galson   |    0.34
> Sam      |    0.5
```

I need to display this table in my web app with something like this:

```
> NAME    |     Jon     |   Galson   |    Sam
> VALUE   |     0.2     |    0.34    |    0.5
```

I just want to convert database column into rows using MYSQL + PHP only for display purpose.

Comment: In PHP, this is a simple loop acting upon a well-ordered array.

Comment: Brother I have just tried mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_ASSOC inside while loop but not getting any idea how to do this. :(

Answer (score 2):

You should not be doing this using a (probably complex) SQL query. Instead rely on HTML/CSS for this:

Assuming

```
$data = [{name: 'Jon', value: 0.2}, {name: 'Galson', value: 0.34}, {name: 'Sam', value: 0.5}]
```

you could

```
foreach($data as $person) {
    echo '<div class="person">';
    echo '<div class="name">' . $person->name . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="value">' . $person->value . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and

```
.person {
    float: left; 
}
```

Also *don't*, never ever, under any circumstances, build HTML like that. [Use some kind of templates.](https://www.google.com/?q=php%20templates)

Comment: *why* should the OP use templates for something like this?

Comment: Because most likely this piece of code will fit in a larger context with more loops and more HTML. And maybe he'll need a conditional in there too at some point. And then you end up with bad code that's impossible to read and zero separation between presentation and logic. And if he's just learning then guiding him to learning about what's _good practice_ is now more important than ever.

Comment: I disagree, using php templates to build html is *not good practice* if you can't do it without. That's like telling someone to skip learning JavaScript and just learn jQuery instead. A developer should be able to write the code in its most basic form before using templates/libraries/plugins/addons etc.. to improve that process.

Comment: I don'd disagree with what you said above. I'm not suggesting he skips that step, but then he should already be able to figure that out for himself. My comment at the end of the answer is only supposed to be a big red flag to anyone doing copy-paste programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out @Sergiu Paraschiv answer. What you definitely do not want to do is use the deprecated `mysql_db_query()`. Alternatively try something like this:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT name, value FROM table');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$output = [];

foreach($results as $row) {
    $output[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
print_r($output);
```